# "Warning: require_once(./cli/includes/require-drivers.php): Failed to open stream" when using custom Laravel Valet driver for Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-valet

I'm trying to create a custom Laravel Valet driver for a Symfony project as I need to handle asset files in a specific way. I've created the following `ProjectValetDriver` class in `/.config/valet/Drivers`

```
<?php

namespace Valet\Drivers\Custom;

use Valet\Drivers\LaravelValetDriver;

class ProjectValetDriver extends LaravelValetDriver
{
    public function serves(string $sitePath, string $siteName, string $uri): bool
    {
        return $siteName === '[project-name]';
    }

    public function isStaticFile(string $sitePath, string $siteName, string $uri): string|false
    {
        if (file_exists($staticFilePath = $sitePath.'/public/'.$uri)) {
            return $staticFilePath;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function frontControllerPath(string $sitePath, string $siteName, string $uri): string
    {
        return $sitePath.'/public/index.php';
    }
}
```

The custom driver is correctly registered, however when I visit the site I get the following error;

`Warning: require_once(./cli/includes/require-drivers.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/[user]/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php on line 3`

The `public/index.php` file is called correctly as well, but that file calling `require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';` seems to break everything. Without the custom driver the site loads fine. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Try clearing cache and restarting valet: 'valet forget' & 'valet restart'

Comment: Didn't work sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was ultimately solved by extending `Valet\Drivers\Specific\SymfonyValetDriver` instead of `LaravelValetDriver`. In doing so, I can also ommit the `frontControllerPath` method from the custom driver.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this issue recently as well when trying to run a Symfony application with Laravel Herd.

The issue is that Symfony 5.3+ introduced a new runtime that detects the front controller to begin execution. The front controller *should* be the `public/index.php` file, but since you are running this through Laravel Valet, the front controller is Valet's `server.php`, which causes the issues you are facing.

The solution is to override a few of the `$_SERVER` globals to change the front controller and allow Symfony's runtime to take over.

```php
<?php

namespace Valet\Drivers\Custom;

use Valet\Drivers\LaravelValetDriver;

class ProjectValetDriver extends LaravelValetDriver
{
    public function serves(string $sitePath, string $siteName, string $uri): bool
    {
        return $siteName === '[project-name]';
    }

    public function isStaticFile(string $sitePath, string $siteName, string $uri): string|false
    {
        if (file_exists($staticFilePath = $sitePath.'/public/'.$uri)) {
            return $staticFilePath;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function frontControllerPath($sitePath, $siteName, $uri)
    {
        $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = $sitePath.'/public/index.php';
        $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/index.php';

        return $sitePath.'/public/index.php';
    }
}
```

Lastly, run `valet restart` to reload your driver.

Now, when Valet serves your Symfony project, it should properly delegate control to your app's `public/index.php`, and the application should run as expected.

Comment: I actually solved it by extending `Valet\Drivers\Specific\SymfonyValetDriver` instead of extending `LaravelValetDriver`. I'll add my own answer.